# HDF-EOS: compilation/linking error c/c++

Tags: c, hdf

I am trying to compile an example program to use HDF-EOS. The example code is taken from the HDF-EOS [website](http://hdfeos.org/examples/code/read_datafield_grid_AE_RnGd.c) (I will therefore only post the top section):

```
/* This example shows how to read a data field in HDF-EOS2 grid data. */

#include <mfhdf.h>
#include <hdf.h>
#include <HdfEosDef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int32 gridfile1;
    int32 grid1;
    int32 datafield1rank;
    int32 datafield1dimsize[32];
    int32 datafield1type;
    char datafield1dimname[512];
    float32 *datafield1data;
    int32 i, j;

    /* Open 'AMSR_E_L3_RainGrid_B05_200707.hdf' using grid API */
    if ((gridfile1 = GDopen("AMSR_E_L3_RainGrid_B05_200707.hdf", DFACC_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot open grid 'AMSR_E_L3_RainGrid_B05_200707.hdf'\n");
        return -1;
    }

return 0;
```

The corresponding make file looks like this:

```
HDF4_DIR=<hdf4_path>
HDFEOS2_DIR=<hdfeos2_path>

CC=$(HDF4_DIR)/bin/h4cc

CFLAGS=-I$(HDFEOS2_DIR)/include
LDFLAGS=-L$(HDFEOS2_DIR)/lib
LIBS=-lhdfeos -lGctp

read_grid: read_grid.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< $(LIBS) -o $@
```

In addition to the above mentioned paths I have also added links to the hdf5 library, so my make file looks like this:

```
HDF4_DIR=<hdf4_path>
HDFEOS2_DIR=<hdfeos2_path>
HDF5_DIR=<hdf5_path>

CC=$(HDF4_DIR)/bin/h4cc

CFLAGS=-I$(HDFEOS2_DIR)/include -I$(HDF4_DIR)/include -I$(HDF5_DIR)/include
LDFLAGS=-L$(HDFEOS2_DIR)/lib64 -L$(HDF4_DIR)/lib64 -L$(HDF5_DIR)/lib64
LIBS=-lhdfeos -lGctp

read_grid: read_grid.c
    $(CC) read_hdf_eos.c $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

The problem now is that it does not compile, throwing linking errors such like this:

```
<hdfeos2_path>/lib64/libhdfeos.a(GDapi.o): In function `lamazDxDtheta':
<hdfeos2_path>/src/GDapi.c:9579: undefined reference to `sin'
<hdfeos2_path>/src/GDapi.c:9580: undefined reference to `sin'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So for me this looks like a linking problem, however I have no idea why.
To add to the confusion I get another error:

```
read_grid.o: In function `main':
read_grid.c:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
read_grid.o:read_grid.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
```

Of course I have not defined `main` more than once. In a second example program that throws the same linking errors I do not get this error.

So if some one would have an idea on the first problem, the linking, I would be very happy.

SOLUTION:

1. add -lm at the end of the compile statement in the, removes the linking problem
2. remove the read_hdf_eos.c in the compile statement, that caused the multiple `main` issue

Thanks for the comments and hints.

Comment: Have you checked if read_grid.c has defined another main function?

Comment: @MarcColl I have checked and there is none. You can see the entire code in the provided link, the parts I did not post are some opening and read statements, but not another main

Comment: How many web search results did you get when you tried to look up "undefined reference to sin"? How many of those have you reviewed?

Comment: @n.m. ok, adding -lm solved the `sin` issue, now just the multiple definition of main remains. Thanks.

Comment: `$(CC) read_hdf_eos.cpp $(CFLAGS)  ...` What is this .cpp source doing here ? does it have a main(), too ?

Comment: You cannot possibly be getting both errors at the same time. Specify which error results from which command/makefile.

Comment: @joop the .cpp was a c&p error, it was actually only .c, but nevertheless this statement was causing the multiple main error. Now it seems to work. Thanks.